# SSIS dataflow cannot aquire connection even though it did earlier in the control flow

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a package that connects to two different DBs, does some calculations, and then inserts values into each DB.  The package worked great in our old env, but migrating it over to the new one has proven pretty unpleasant.  We had to switch from Windows Auth to SQL Auth and the Connection Manager test works fine, but I'm getting the following error when attempting to execute my SSIS package from Visual Studio:

> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.
> The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "DB1"
> failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted
> before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method
> call failed.

> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: OLE DB Source failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC020801C.

What has me really puzzled is the failing task isn't even the first time that connection is used in the package.  Just before reaching that Dataflow task, an Execute SQL Task fires against the same connection and is successful.  I can also go into the task itself and hit "Preview" and it returns data.

Does anyone have any ideas where else to look?

I've tried:

- setting to 32bit Execution
- deleting and recreating the task
- delay validation = true

Comment: What's the transaction option on the tasks (unsupported/supported/required)? Is retain same connection set to true? Do you need to enlist a distributed transaction? You said you had to switch from windows to SQL auth - did you move one or both of your databases to azure?

Comment: The task is wrapped in a sequence container, which has a TransactionOption of Required.  The task itself has a TransactionOption of Supported.  Retain Connection is false.  This does use a distributed transaction and DTC is enabled on both servers.  One of the environments was moved to Azure, which is why we had to switch to SQL auth.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific: Are you on Azure SQL, or an Azure VM running regular SQL? Since you said you had to switch to SQL auth I figured Azure SQL, but that would preclude being able to enable DTC for XA transactions

Comment: Ah, sorry.  We're on Azure VM running regular SQL

Comment: OK, my bet is that it's still something to do with distributed transactions. If the execute SQL task is also happening in the transaction scope, you may need to set retain same connection to true - distributed transactions don't like multiple connections. If it still fails, double check that MSDTC is actually configured correctly (network dtc access checked, allow inbound, allow outbound), and if that *still* fails, maybe [RPC is being firewalled](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/250367/configuring-microsoft-distributed-transaction-coordinator-dtc-to-work)

Comment: As you can see this is right at the edge of my knowledge - I guess an easy way to check if this is the issue would be to try it in dev without transactional support. But you *should* be able to get a distributed transaction here (just not with azure SQL)

Comment: I'll give those ideas a shot.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Good luck, and do come let me know, you have my curiosity piqued